# Webservice returns anyType{} android

Tags: android, getresponse, envelope

I'm new in the programming world, so I just need some help.
I must consume a webservice on android. I've already done one that works fine, but the problem happens when I have to pass a parameter. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code of the AsyncTask:

```
public class PegaHorarioProfessorTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String URL = "http://fatec.aied.com.br/publico.asmx?WSDL"; //"10.68.76.4/publico.asmx?WSDL";  //        http://fatec.aied.com.br/publico.asmx?WSDL
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HorarioProfessor";

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            String frase = null;

            SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "HorarioProfessor");

            String id = "11";

            PropertyInfo profId =new PropertyInfo();
            profId.setName("Id");
            profId.setValue(id);
            profId.setType(String.class);
            soap.addAttribute("Id", id);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            SoapObject result = null;

            try {

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultado1 = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                //result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                //result.getProperty(0);

                if (result != null) {
                    Log.i("Result", result.toString());
                    return result.toString();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result.toString();

        }
    }
```

So, I pass the ID 11 and it returns 2 Strings. The problem is: it doesn't return anything besides 'anyType{}', and I'm not sure how to receive two strings. I've commented two lines, because I'm not sure if it's better to get the result by envelope.bodyIn or envelope.getResponse().

Maybe, it's necessary to post the Activity that receives the result:

```
public class ActivityHorarioProfessor extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario_professor);

        String[] aux = null;

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Professores professor = (Professores) intent.getSerializableExtra("professorSelecionado");
        if(professor!=null) {
            PegaHorarioProfessorTask prof = new PegaHorarioProfessorTask();
            Log.i("Número", String.valueOf(prof));
            String auxi = null;
            try {
                auxi = prof.execute().get().toString();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("Auxi", String.valueOf(auxi));
        }
        else {
            Log.i("It's", "WRONG");
        }

    }
}
```

It just gives back an empty (anyType{}) answer.

Comment: can you request for data in json or xml which would be more flexible to code, hrskrs has already addressed your question

Answer (score 1):

> It just gives back an empty (anyType{}) answer.

This means that there is no any `data` returning.

However if you dont want to get `anyType{}` but an `empty string`:

Instead of:

```
result.getProperty(0);
```

use:

```
result.getPrimitivePropertyAsString(0);
```

Here is an example on how to get data from `webservice` using `KSOAP` (***If you are expecting `String` as a `response`***):

```
public static String getDataAsString(){
    String responseString = "";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty(KEY, value);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = getHttpTransportSE();
    try {
      httpTransportSE.call(ACTION_NAME, envelope);
      SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
      responseString = response.toString();

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
      soapFault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

`getSoapSerializationEnvelope` function:

```
 public static final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request){
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        return envelope;
    }
```

`getHttpTransportSE` function:

```
 public static final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE(){
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
        return ht;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example it'll be helpful. But the problem is that when I run it on SoapUI, sending 11, it returns two Strings. By the code it returns an empty result, not the two strings.

Comment: @ViniciusCruz then check if you are sending right `METHOD_NAME` and gettiong right `response`. Specifically check `HorarioProfessor` and `professorSelecionado`